# when i check my site on google page speed it will showed me preload error from some font in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, performance

Hello am facing issues with preload error on google page speed in my site  can anyone help me with this I try to check on many threads online but not any answer work for me if anyone help here really appreciates thanks in advance

currently, I want to implement this on my WordPress site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code

```
<link rel='preload' href="your font url which shows on google page speed" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>
```

Comment: I hope its work because this is something unique form other answers which I show online let me check with it thanks for your replay

Comment: Hey @Pixlogix add this code in my website but still its not working

please cehck is it correct or not  <link rel='preload' href="https://example.com/myfont.wtf" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin>

Comment: if you have any caching plugin then please clear the cache

Comment: ohhh yes it's my mistake sorry thanks it's working now really appreciates pixlogix